# REALLOCATED SECTOR COUNT 4948. Request for advice

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive, storage, smart, hard-drive-failure

[image: Image of HD Tune Pro HEALTH report]

I felt need of testing because some of my stored games were failing to boot properly. Quick test from HD Tune Pro app displayed 3 red blocks in one of the test runs and a full test always reports 3 Red blocks of bad sectors.

Hence:

1. How bad is it in a count from 1-10 (Score of 1 being worst and 10 being Flawless)
2. I am currently using it as external expansion drive for games for my xbox. To extend whatever life possible should i better use it for storing 4K UHD BluRay Rips that i stream with plex. Basically i want to know out of these two usage scenarios what puts the least stress on the drive and potentially buys me some time.

Comment: It's bad, in a nutshell.

Comment: note that bad sectors tend to increase exponentially to time, so get your data off that disk ASAP.

Comment: I suggest not using it for anything that you would be unhappy at losing. *Now* is the time to make a backup of anything you don't want to lose.

Answer (score 3):

4948 reallocated sectors would be plenty reason for me to replace the drive. As you can read others may have different opinions. Which kind of shows the difficulty in answering this type of questions, it's mostly a matter of opinion, or experience perhaps, but there are no rules carved in stone that tell us to replace a drive if number of reallocated sectors reaches [insert number or percentage here].

I assert that many people asking about an x number of reallocated sectors are seeking reassurance. And so fact that this number is non zero in itself causes an uneasy feeling. The simplest answer I think is simply replacing the drive if you want peace of mind.

Any drive can fail at any point without warning. In addition to that, I think there's evidence that supports the statement that any drive with non zero reallocated sectors has a higher chance of failing 'soon' than one with zero reallocations (and pending reallocation sectors), for example: https://research.google/pubs/failure-trends-in-a-large-disk-drive-population/.

OTOH one might argue, with > 1000 sectors to spare, why worry about 100 reallocated sectors? Or with 10000 to spare, why worry about 4948 reallocated sectors? While the question sounds reasonable, I personally think it's a bad idea to wait until the number of reallocated sectors reaches the point where it causes the normalized value to reach the threshold as set by the manufacturer.

Another point that can be made, is to observe if whatever number of reallocated sectors we have is *static* or *increasing*. I agree one could argue that if the number is static there's less reason for concern compared to the situation where we see the number steadily increase. I once had a drive that got rejected by a RAID controller due to two recorded reallocations, I have used the drive for years without the number ever changing. Still, IMO there's a difference between 2 or 4948 reallocations.

One may argue we can try to see number of reallocations in relation to other attributes. Now this may be less straight forward than it may seem. While reallocated sectors is pretty standard across manufacturers, many other attributes are not. So one may interpret reallocations as 'soft' errors based on values of other attributes, in reality a drive reallocating a sector means the sector is *physically* unusable. The drive will reallocate once it has determined a sector is no longer safe to use. So either drive determines it can not write to the sector or it can not reliably read back what it just wrote. A soft error that is recoverable can be resolved by writing recover data back to the exact same sector. Reallocation by definition means the drive deemed it a hard error.

Comment: Thank you so much for your valuable insight. What do you suggest what can be the best possible use case out of the two to get maximum life 1. Using it for storing and streaming 4K BluRay Rips OR 2. Using it as an expansion drive for Xbox games. Out of these two cases which can cause degradation faster. I won’t be using this drive for storing irreplaceable personal stuff and just want to put it for some use till it dies for good

Comment: I would 1. suggest not using the drive at all .. 2. Run full scan using something like Victoria for Windows to see if those 4948 sectors are it or that more are 'lurking'.

Comment: @KkyleReese, do you have backups or the ability to regen any lost data? personally i cringe at the idea of running a disk into the ground, but that's just me. if you can recover from a failure, that's all that's important. neither usecase is likely to extend lifespan over the other.

Comment: @FrankThomas yes in both scenarios data is very much recoverable and that’s why I want to know the best possible way to use the drive. I guess I am better of using it for storing and streaming BluRay rips over Plex. I believe this usage is better than playing Games from it. I know both use cases are not ideal for a failing drive but i just want to use it till it breathes last

Answer (score 1):

I'd say *most* modern drives have some bad sectors and its a 'pre failure' issue. You probably need to/want to look at your *pending* reallocation count, and any number other than zero there is a bad thing.

That *does* appear to be an older drive, and external drives tend to sometimes not be as robust.

Its also worth remembering/deciding if the data *can* be recovered easily. On one hand, should the drive die, you can re-download your xbox games. On the other hand, your  4K UHD BluRay Rips could be reripped if you have the disks and video playback *tends* to have error correction built in.

Game files are large, constant reads. Video tends to be bursty, probably needs a lower data rate, and you're likely to put less running hours into the drive.  If you're using this more for transient than long term storage and with data you don't care about the integrity of - I'd just wipe the drive when it gives trouble, reformat it again, and run it till the next time it gave trouble.

Answer (score -2):

On the count from 1-10 : I would give your disk a badness level of 9 (where 10 is extremely bad and 0 is perfect health).

This number means that 4948 sectors died on you, but the disk firmware
has managed to relocate/remap them to spare sectors. This number is
very large and shows a disk that I wouldn't trust in the long term.

The reason I don't give it 10 is that the evaluation of the disk's firmware
of this parameter was 77, while the failure threshold was 36.
This means that the disk has more than 10000 spare sectors.
In addition, the "Uncorrectable Error Count" is zero, so you had had no
sectors with hard failure.

You may continue to use the disk, just ensure you have backups for the
important files. Keep an eye on the two parameters of
"Reallocated Sector Count" and "Uncorrectable Error Count".
If either one starts climbing up, then the disk's state is degrading.

Comment: Firmware *managing* to reallocate sectors sounds like an accomplishment but of course it's a simple remapping operation. With regards to BB attribute, one could argue it's bad translation, Seagate self call BB attribute BB "Reported Uncorrectables". **Reported**!
I have seen examples of the BB attribute reporting zero while SMART logs actually showed > zero values (HDDGuru forums).
4948 reallocations and then giving a hard drive 9 out of 10 health rating is ridiculous.

Comment: @JoepvanSteen: Remapping is an accomplishment, because it means that these sectors were readable after some retries. With 4948 unreadable sectors the disk is dead. My 9 for the badness level means untrustworthy but not yet dead. Would you give it a much better "badness note"?

Comment: No it does not mean sectors were readable after retries, most reallocations don't happen on read. Scale was 1(very bad) - 10 (flawless), this drive is nowhere near 10.

Comment: @JoepvanSteen: We understand the scale differently. My 9 is your 2 apparently. I'll clarify it in my answer.

Comment: Ah, that would explain a lot.

Comment: To the misunderstanding downvoters: With the enormous number of 10-15,000 spare sectors, and with a firmware that hasn't let a single weak sector become a hard error by early remapping, this is a high-quality disk that was made to last. It has used up exactly 23% of its spare sectors. It's not young, but may still serve for years with a bit of luck, although some caution is required given its age. What's missing is the element of time, to see if these SMART attributes are stable and the disk can still serve, or if not and then the disk has to be replaced now.

Comment: A down-voter is not by definition a "mis-understander". One reason of drives having a large number of spare sectors is so they can be spread over the drive so that reallocations can be done relatively local to the sector to be reallocated. This is one of the conclusions of a large scale study done by Google: "After their first reallocation, drives are over 14 times more likely to fail within 60 days than drives without reallocation counts, making the critical threshold for this parameter also one.". FWIW I retracted my downvote yesterday.

Comment: @JoepvanSteen: Thanks - I would like to see this link, but my comment wasn't addressed at you. Most consumer disks have 10-20% of this impressive number of spare sectors, and we don't know over how many years the remapped sectors have been developing. What I tried to say is that each disk is different, so has to be judged in context, not to automatically advise to junk a disk that may still see useful usage, but this kind of advice is always downvoted here (from experience).

Comment: https://research.google/pubs/failure-trends-in-a-large-disk-drive-population/

Comment: Thanks to both of you for sharing valuable insight. What do you suggest what can be the best possible use case out of the two to get maximum life 1. Using it for storing and streaming 4K BluRay Rips OR 2. Using it as an expansion drive for Xbox games. Out of these two cases which can cause degradation faster. I won’t be using this drive for storing irreplaceable personal stuff and just want to put it for some use till it dies for good

Comment: @KkyleReese: Writing dynamically to the disk is what will accelerate degradation. Choose the option that means less writing and less having the disk under power. Keep an eye on the above parameters, and if they don't degrade the disk may still serve for years. But if they start degrading, get rid of it.

Comment: I believe using it for storing media and streaming over Plex is better of the two.

Comment: You're likely right. The disk is now old, but its specs were once impressive.

Comment: This discussion clearly outlines how much the subject of bad sectors is opinion-based. Furthermore any hints based on a personal use profile do not add value for future readers.

Comment: harrymc, please provide a source that proves a linear relationship between the attribute value and the number of reallocated sectors - a relationship that you assume. 
The relationsship can be log-related. There is no rule how to derive the attribute value from the raw data. I would appreciate if you could prove me wrong! Thank you.